# Wordpress wp_insert_post () redirect?

Tags: wordpress

Now i create a wordpress front-end post, after wp_insert_post(); i want to redirect into the full page of that post data. Here i use the this way, so it was redirect the blog index page, but i need this page redirect this post full page.

```
      $post_insert = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $content,
        'tags_input'    => $post_tags,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
      );
      $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_insert );
      wp_redirect( site_url()."?post=$post_id" );
      exit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with $post_id being inside the double quotes. Try this instead:

```
wp_redirect( site_url()."?post=".$post_id);
```

Comment: i use this case...but it was redirect to the home page of the post page, i need the particular post full page, like when you go to the blog page u find the all post data, then when you click the title you find the full content of the post, so here i need this full content page..

Comment: can you post here what the value of $post_id looks like in your url?

Comment: i want to redirect, this post into the loop-single.php page

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use this:

```
wp_redirect(get_permalink($post_id));
```

The get_permalink method is the Wordpress built-in method to get a permanent link.
See this url for the documentation for this method: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink