# Redirect user to newly created page via front end form?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a page in Wordpress via a front end form with the code below. On submit, how can I then redirect the user to the newly created page?

UPDATE:
Is it possible to turn the post_title into a url rather than a page ID? So something like company.com/my-company?

```
<?php $postTitle = $_POST['post_title'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if(isset($submit)){

    global $user_ID;

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $postTitle,
        'post_content' => $post,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author' => $user_ID,
        'post_type' => 'members',
        'post_category' => array(0)
    );

    wp_insert_post($new_post);

}

?>



<form action="" method="post">
<table border="1" width="200">
  <tr>
    <td><label for="post_title">Post Title</label></td>
    <td><input name="post_title" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="post">Post</label></td>
    <td><input name="post" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817598/wordpress-wp-insert-post-redirect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wp_redirect()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) - Redirects the user to a specified absolute URI

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to turn the post_title into a url rather than a page ID? So something like http://www.company.com/my-company?

Comment: $page_name = get_permalink( $page_id );

$home_url = get_site_url();

wp_redirect( $home_url."/".$page_name );